# Why online chat is so invasive?

Tags: e-commerce, chat, customer-experience

I analysed the statistics to remove chat from the e-commerce but the online chat has a lot of conversions. On the other side, it is so invasive and absolute boring for customers that don't need or won't like to use the chat.

**What's the best solution to improve the experience for users (most of them) that would not like to use or see chat?**

*Ps.: At the moment, we are showing on the whole website, we are tracking in which page they use more, the chat are located on the right on the bottom (like the most websites) we are using custom pop-up messages for each page and after the user close the pop-up we will not show again. BUT I'm still feeling invasive, mainly in mobile.*

Comment: Whom do the users chat with? Each other or with a rep from the company?

Comment: With specialist support because our product is complex.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into chatbots. They work well for well-documented scenarios and cut the noise. It would also help take some load off the support and improve the accessibility of the FAQ/Help section

Comment: We are doing it. What I would like to improve is the position on the screen, the pop-ups or a different highlight, because at the moment on the desktop on the right bottom is ok, but on mobile is terrible. At really I do not like the current solution of the most chat/chatbots. (I'm not talking about the functionality, I'm talking about the CTA)

Comment: You could always tuck the chat in the help section for mobile. As long as the user doesn't have to jump through hoops to get to it, there's no need for it to be on the screen

Comment: I agree but how can I convince to remove the right bottom if it having a good conversion rate? I didn't find any way to prove that is boring for most users. They are saying, ok... but if I remove probably the user that need will not use anymore and we will lose conversion then because of this I'm looking for alternatives way to display it being less invasive.

Comment: You say chat is invasive and that most of your users don't like it and don't use it. Sounds to me like the solution is to remove chat altogether. How are you getting conversions when most of your users don't use it or like it?

Comment: @Rob I completely agree with you but the few users that use it has 3x more conversions than users that not using. And these conversions represent a significant amount of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 'chat' has two aspects to it:

A)It is used by users "a lot of conversions". So it's a feature you need to keep.

B)Its current incarnation is invasive, meaning the way it is defined on the website interrupts all users' experience.

The solution must serve two functions:
It must tell users of its existence;
Its existence must not interrupt the users' experience

I would suggest changing the way it functions so it is only *visibly obvious*. This means ditch the pop-up behaviour and style the pop-up feature in a way that contrasts in an eye catching manner to the rest of the page. A suggestion would be a different colour or something flashing subtly. Your solution must draw the users eye but not in a way that interrupts their experience.

Reference: nngroup.com/articles/chat-ux

Comment: Cool! Do you have some good chat reference?

Comment: Yes, I have a very good reference here https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chat-ux/

Comment: That link should be included in the answer.